# Multiple W10 installations after bad update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

After a W10 update my pc was stuck on a "*Restoring to Previous Version*" loop.

I tried to fix MBR via command line and after that I saw that on my machine there was 3 installation of W10. I tried all of them and one works.

It seems to be an old version of W10 without any update. My msconfig look like this:

[image]

The working OS is the last one (C:\WINDOWS).

What can I do now ? Should I just delete the other two ?

Comment: Remove that first line from boot manager (as seen in that image). Then delete the C:\$Windows.~BT folder. No need the reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, backup your personal data.

Then, format C partition and reinstall Windows 10 again.

You don’t need two Windows 10 OS, to say the least, if you need dual system, the second system should be installed in another partition rather than C partition.